# Can I install Google Chrome and Chromium together?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Can I install Google Chrome browser and Chromium together in Ubuntu? Are there any known conflicts when I install both of them together?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Yes

They are different programs. I am currently running both with no issues

Comment: Thak you, I install both of them and do not have any problem.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

You can download here:
https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/

then install:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_YOUR_VERSION.deb
```

Comment: I'm not sure the `dpkg` step is needed. Just follow the instructions that appear when you click on the link Sergio provided. Google will set up everything. At least that's been my experience when I installed it in clean installs of 11.10 and 12.04.

Comment: @vasa1 You still need to manually install it by clicking on the deb file and opening it in software-center or by the suggested terminal command.

Comment: @jokerdino, yes, that's it. Right-clicking suggests opening via the USC.